# Who is Uncle Bobby, the old blind man in a wheelchair in the pub?

Tags: character-identification, adaptation-comparison, miss-peregrines-home

In the Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children movie, we are introduced to an old man named Uncle Bobby.  The only thing he seems to do is hang out at the local pub being blind and in a wheelchair.  However we learn

> after his death that he is a peculiar,

but never any details about that or him at all.

Is there any information on this character either in the movie or the book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the wiki entry](http://thepeculiarchildren.wikia.com/wiki/Uncle_Bobby):

> Uncle Bobby is the brother of Les and Maryann, and uncle of Jacob Portman and one of the owners of the family convenience store chain Smart Aid.

However, within the books, he is a [Coerlfolc](http://thepeculiarchildren.wikia.com/wiki/Coerlfolc_(Species)), someone without powers, and is not in a wheelchair.

I think you're confusing this with an anonymous fellow in the pub who is later found dead with his eyes torn out. [This fellow feels](https://www.quora.com/Who-was-the-old-man-in-the-wheelchair-in-Miss-Peregrines-Home-movie) that he was intended as bait, to get Jacob to run to Miss Peregrine and reveal their location.

> Hollows do kill people with no peculiarities if they come in their way while reaching the peculiar. However, it seemed that the old man was killed by the traveling book writer (Mr. Barron) at the beach so that Jake and all other villagers had to come to the beach and seeing hollow eyes of the dead wheelchair guy (similar to his grandpa's eyes post death) would make him suspicious and he will run towards the peculiar home (like he did) and this would also lead Mr. Barron to Miss Peregrine's home for peculiar children which he wanted.

I do not believe that he appears in the book.